# Add secondary x-axis to plot

Tags: plotly-dash

I would like to add a secondary x-axis with `df[time2]` to a plot. This is the code:

```
fig_zoom = px.scatter(df5
                                  , x = "time"
                                  , y = 'value'
                                  , color = 'variable'
                                  , symbol = 'variable'
                                  , opacity = 0.5
                                  , template = 'plotly_dark'
                                  , title = device_name
                                  , color_discrete_map = {"I_A": 'orangered', "I_fil" : 'lawngreen', "V+" : "dodgerblue", "V-" : "chocolate"}
                                  )
        fig_zoom.update_traces(marker = dict(
                                                size = 5
                                                )
                               )
        fig_zoom.update_layout(
                               transition_duration = 500
                               , autosize = True
                               , height = 600
                               , hovermode='x unified'
                               , hoverlabel=dict(
                                                 bgcolor="rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)", 
                                                 font_size=14, 
                                                 font_family="Rockwell"
                                                 )
                              )
        return fig_zoom
```

is there an easy way to go? I've seen only examples to use `go.scatter()` with traces and stuff which is quite different..?